# How to edit image using jquery cropper which is stored on amazon webservice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a [jquery cropper (v 0.7.9) plugin](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/v0.7.9/) which is used to edit image. I just created a simple example on my machine by following instructions given in plugin's page. It works fine if the image is stored on my machine. But its not working if the image is from amazon bucket. Please give me suggestion for the following code.

```
<div class="eg-wrapper" id="divContainer" style="height: 400px;width: 400px;">
        <img class="cropper" id="editImage" crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://review-rating-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/9991710/149270397024phpG2BOu7.jpeg" alt="Picture" height="400" width="400">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="getDataURL" type="button">Get Data URL</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="getDataURL2" type="button">Get Data URL (JPG)</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="getDataURL3" type="button">Get Data URL (160*90)</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="rotate" type="button">Rotate</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="zoom" type="button">Zoom</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="getImageData" type="button">Get Image Data</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="getData2" type="button">Get Data (Rounded)</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="getData" type="button">Get Data</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
<button class="btn  btn-warning" id="reset2" type="button">Reset (deep)</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="clear" type="button">Clear</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="destroy" type="button">Destroy</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="enable" type="button">Enable</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="disable" type="button">Disable</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="zoomIn" type="button">Zoom In</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="zoomOut" type="button">Zoom Out</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="rotateLeft" type="button">Rotate Left</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="rotateRight" type="button">Rotate Right</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="setData" type="button">Set Data</button>
<br/>
<textarea class="form-control" id="dataURL" rows="10"></textarea>
<script>
    var $image = $("#editImage"),
          $dataX = $("#dataX"),
          $dataY = $("#dataY"),
          $dataHeight = $("#dataHeight"),
          $dataWidth = $("#dataWidth"),
          console = window.console || { log: function () {} },
          cropper;

      $image.cropper({
        // autoCropArea: 1,
        data: {
          x: 50,
          y: 50,
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        },

        // multiple: true,
        // autoCrop: false,
        // dragCrop: false,
        // dashed: false,
        // modal: false,
        // movable: false,
        // resizable: false,
        // zoomable: false,
        // rotatable: false,
        // checkImageOrigin: false,

        // maxWidth: 480,
        // maxHeight: 270,
        // minWidth: 160,
        // minHeight: 90,

        done: function (data) {
          $dataX.val(data.x);
          $dataY.val(data.y);
          $dataHeight.val(data.height);
          $dataWidth.val(data.width);
        },

        build: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        },

        built: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        },

        dragstart: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        },

        dragmove: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        },

        dragend: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        }
      });

      cropper = $image.data("cropper");

      $image.on({
        "build.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        },
        "built.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        },
        "dragstart.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        },
        "dragmove.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        },
        "dragend.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

      $("#reset").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("reset");
      });

      $("#reset2").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("reset", true);
      });

      $("#clear").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("clear");
      });

      $("#destroy").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("destroy");
      });

      $("#enable").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("enable");
      });

      $("#disable").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("disable");
      });

      $("#zoom").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", $("#zoomWith").val());
      });

      $("#zoomIn").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", 0.1);
      });

      $("#zoomOut").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", -0.1);
      });

      $("#rotate").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("rotate", $("#rotateWith").val());
      });

      $("#rotateLeft").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("rotate", -90);
      });

      $("#rotateRight").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("rotate", 90);
      });

      var $inputImage = $("#inputImage"),
          blobURL;

      if (window.URL) {
        $inputImage.change(function () {
          var files = this.files,
              file;

          if (files && files.length) {
            file = files[0];

            if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
              if (blobURL) {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke the old one
              }

              blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
              $image.cropper("reset", true).cropper("replace", blobURL);
              $inputImage.val("");
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        $inputImage.parent().remove();
      }

      $("#setAspectRatio").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("setAspectRatio", $("#aspectRatio").val());
      });

      $("#replace").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("replace", $("#replaceWith").val());
      });

      $("#getImageData").click(function () {
        $("#showImageData").val(JSON.stringify($image.cropper("getImageData")));
      });

      $("#setData").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("setData", {
          x: $dataX.val(),
          y: $dataY.val(),
          width: $dataWidth.val(),
          height: $dataHeight.val()
        });
      });

      $("#getData").click(function () {
        $("#showData").val(JSON.stringify($image.cropper("getData")));
      });

      $("#getData2").click(function () {
        $("#showData").val(JSON.stringify($image.cropper("getData", true)));
      });

      $("#getDataURL").click(function () {
        var dataURL = $image.cropper("getDataURL");
        alert(dataURL);
        $("#dataURL").text(dataURL);
        $("#showDataURL").html('<img src="' + dataURL + '">');
      });

      $("#getDataURL2").click(function () {
        var dataURL = $image.cropper("getDataURL", "image/jpeg");
        alert(dataURL);
        $("#dataURL").text(dataURL);
        $("#showDataURL").html('<img src="' + dataURL + '">');
      });

      $("#getDataURL3").click(function () {
        var dataURL = $image.cropper("getDataURL", {
          width: 160,
          height: 90
        });
        alert(dataURL);
        $("#dataURL").text(dataURL);
        $("#showDataURL").html('<img src="' + dataURL + '">');
      });
</script>
```

Comment: your problem is when you ar sveng image or when is cropping it

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón didn't got what you want to say.

Comment: yes, if didnt crop athe image. Or didnt save the image. Whats rthe matter

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón the image is displaying correctly, but the cropper is not working.

Comment: when is a external image, mm . Rare because when is loaded in your page, then is  a canvas, and not impartant where it comes

Comment: So how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made this [demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/1ag5uer3/), to begin to study and solve your problem with amazon.
And the image from amazon didnt display it. And when a try to access directly to image, it was downloaded.

So i think will be a problem of permissions in amazon with this image.

```
<div class="eg-wrapper" id="divContainer" style="height: 400px;width: 400px;">
        <img class="cropper" id="editImage" crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://review-rating-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/9991710/149270397024phpG2BOu7.jpeg" alt="Picture" height="400" width="400">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="getDataURL" type="button">Get Data URL</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="getDataURL2" type="button">Get Data URL (JPG)</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="getDataURL3" type="button">Get Data URL (160*90)</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="rotate" type="button">Rotate</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="zoom" type="button">Zoom</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="getImageData" type="button">Get Image Data</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="getData2" type="button">Get Data (Rounded)</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="getData" type="button">Get Data</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
<button class="btn  btn-warning" id="reset2" type="button">Reset (deep)</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="clear" type="button">Clear</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" id="destroy" type="button">Destroy</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="enable" type="button">Enable</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="disable" type="button">Disable</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="zoomIn" type="button">Zoom In</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="zoomOut" type="button">Zoom Out</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="rotateLeft" type="button">Rotate Left</button>
<button class="btn btn-info" id="rotateRight" type="button">Rotate Right</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="setData" type="button">Set Data</button>
<br/>
<textarea class="form-control" id="dataURL" rows="10"></textarea>
<script>
    var $image = $("#editImage"),
          $dataX = $("#dataX"),
          $dataY = $("#dataY"),
          $dataHeight = $("#dataHeight"),
          $dataWidth = $("#dataWidth"),
          console = window.console || { log: function () {} },
          cropper;

      $image.cropper({
        // autoCropArea: 1,
        data: {
          x: 50,
          y: 50,
          width: 200,
          height: 200
        },

        // multiple: true,
        // autoCrop: false,
        // dragCrop: false,
        // dashed: false,
        // modal: false,
        // movable: false,
        // resizable: false,
        // zoomable: false,
        // rotatable: false,
        // checkImageOrigin: false,

        // maxWidth: 480,
        // maxHeight: 270,
        // minWidth: 160,
        // minHeight: 90,

        done: function (data) {
          $dataX.val(data.x);
          $dataY.val(data.y);
          $dataHeight.val(data.height);
          $dataWidth.val(data.width);
        },

        build: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        },

        built: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        },

        dragstart: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        },

        dragmove: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        },

        dragend: function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
        }
      });

      cropper = $image.data("cropper");

      $image.on({
        "build.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        },
        "built.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        },
        "dragstart.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        },
        "dragmove.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        },
        "dragend.cropper": function (e) {
          console.log(e.type);
          // e.preventDefault();
        }
      });

      $("#reset").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("reset");
      });

      $("#reset2").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("reset", true);
      });

      $("#clear").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("clear");
      });

      $("#destroy").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("destroy");
      });

      $("#enable").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("enable");
      });

      $("#disable").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("disable");
      });

      $("#zoom").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", $("#zoomWith").val());
      });

      $("#zoomIn").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", 0.1);
      });

      $("#zoomOut").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("zoom", -0.1);
      });

      $("#rotate").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("rotate", $("#rotateWith").val());
      });

      $("#rotateLeft").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("rotate", -90);
      });

      $("#rotateRight").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("rotate", 90);
      });

      var $inputImage = $("#inputImage"),
          blobURL;

      if (window.URL) {
        $inputImage.change(function () {
          var files = this.files,
              file;

          if (files && files.length) {
            file = files[0];

            if (/^image\/\w+$/.test(file.type)) {
              if (blobURL) {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke the old one
              }

              blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
              $image.cropper("reset", true).cropper("replace", blobURL);
              $inputImage.val("");
            }
          }
        });
      } else {
        $inputImage.parent().remove();
      }

      $("#setAspectRatio").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("setAspectRatio", $("#aspectRatio").val());
      });

      $("#replace").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("replace", $("#replaceWith").val());
      });

      $("#getImageData").click(function () {
        $("#showImageData").val(JSON.stringify($image.cropper("getImageData")));
      });

      $("#setData").click(function () {
        $image.cropper("setData", {
          x: $dataX.val(),
          y: $dataY.val(),
          width: $dataWidth.val(),
          height: $dataHeight.val()
        });
      });

      $("#getData").click(function () {
        $("#showData").val(JSON.stringify($image.cropper("getData")));
      });

      $("#getData2").click(function () {
        $("#showData").val(JSON.stringify($image.cropper("getData", true)));
      });

      $("#getDataURL").click(function () {
        var dataURL = $image.cropper("getDataURL");
        alert(dataURL);
        $("#dataURL").text(dataURL);
        $("#showDataURL").html('<img src="' + dataURL + '">');
      });

      $("#getDataURL2").click(function () {
        var dataURL = $image.cropper("getDataURL", "image/jpeg");
        alert(dataURL);
        $("#dataURL").text(dataURL);
        $("#showDataURL").html('<img src="' + dataURL + '">');
      });

      $("#getDataURL3").click(function () {
        var dataURL = $image.cropper("getDataURL", {
          width: 160,
          height: 90
        });
        alert(dataURL);
        $("#dataURL").text(dataURL);
        $("#showDataURL").html('<img src="' + dataURL + '">');
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Access control origin is allowed for * (i.e. all) and Read/Write permission is granted. Any more suggestions?

Comment: 1 more, I'm using cropper 0.7.9, so I can export edited image for download or store as new image on amazon.

Comment: so, why is not showed in demo? and is downloaded by browser when try to access by url?

Comment: I'm trying on my machine, its showing. I'm not getting why its not showing on jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm new bee with amazon s3, I've checked permission and access control with my colleague.

Comment: the premissions, is only by your machine, sure. Try to look by this way

Comment: might be issue of permissions, bcoz its working on my local machine as my colleague have made changes in amazon s3. Also Image is displaying on the demo fiddle given by you, but 1 qstn, its working on my local machine, but not working on your fiddle.